# nginx expires on images - subdir override expires

Tags: nginx

I have a nginx configuration where all images etc have set expires headers.. But in one specific directory I want to override the expires?

How?

```
location ~ \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)$ {
    expires 1w;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

location /gfx/munin/ {
    expires off;
}
```

Comment: Is there anything else except images in that subdir?

Comment: there are only .png files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `^~` flag to disable regexp location search for files in `/gfx/munin/`:

```
location ^~ /gfx/munin/ {
    expires off;
}
```

See http://nginx.org/r/location for details.

Comment: I think that this will work because regexp-locations are processed after non-regexp-locations, right?
A more general question here could be: can an expires override another expires? I think that the answer is no.

Comment: @PaulLibbrecht, although nginx could “visit” several location while processing the request (due to `index`, `rewrite`, `try_files` and some other directives that could tell nginx “to go” to another location) it will only use directives from last one. So no matter how many locations it visit only `expires` directive from last one will be used. And if it's not there nginx doesn't care if it was in any previously visited locations. But don't forget about nesting and directive inheritance.

Comment: Right. But what if there's an expire in the server then in a location?